# Can I make custom elements in HTML? If so, how?

Tags: c#

I would like to make an element

for example something like

```
<header>
</header>
```

or like

```
<headerItem>
</headerItem>
```

and I would like to know how to style them in CSS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `<header>` as you suggested and to reference it in css, instead of using "." or "#" to reference a class or ID respectively, you just use the element name, for example, for 
`<header>`

The css would look like this:

```
header {
   background-color: black;
   /* Whatever */
}
```